# Read from firestore collections is too slow

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase.firestore with React. I used firebase method in componentDidMount and items of post is loading too slow.

```
const list = []; 
firebase.firestore().collection("posts").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            list.push(doc.data().message);
        });
    });
```

When push action's done, I change state in React with that variable, but too slow. Any idea?

Comment: how big is querySnapshot? how much time is it taking to do this?

Comment: It has too little entry. It takes 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Things you can try :

1) use .addSnapshotListener() instead of .get()
2) Disable offline persistence
3) Clear the cache/data of your app or device.